# Pandas Python - Finding Time Series Not Covered

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Hoping someone can help me out with this one because I don't even know where to start.

Given a data frame that contains a series of start and end times, such as:

```
Order   Start Time              End Time
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.000 2016-08-18 09:30:05.000
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.005 2016-08-18 09:30:25.001
1       2016-08-18 09:30:30.001 2016-08-18 09:30:56.002
1       2016-08-18 09:30:40.003 2016-08-18 09:31:05.003
1       2016-08-18 11:30:45.000 2016-08-18 13:31:05.000
```

For each order id, I am looking to find a list of time periods that are not covered by any of the ranges between the earliest start time and latest end time

So in the example above, I would be looking for

```
2016-08-18 09:30:05.000 to 2016-08-18 09:30:00.005 (the time lag between the first and second rows)
2016-08-18 09:30:25.001 to 2016-08-18 09:30:30.001 (the time lag between the second and third rows)
```

and

```
2016-08-18 09:31:05.003 to 2016-08-18 11:30:45.000 (the time period between 4 and 5)
```

There is overlap between the 3 and 4 rows, so they wouldn't count

**A few things to consider (additional color):**

Each record indicates an outstanding order placed at (for example) one of the stock exchanges.  Therefore, I can have orders open at Nasdaq and NYSE at the same time.  I also can have a short duration order at Nasdaq and a long one at NYSE starting at the same time.

That would look as following:

```
Order   Start Time              End Time
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.000 2016-08-18 09:30:05.000  (NYSE)
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.001 2016-08-18 09:30:00.002  (NASDAQ)
```

I am trying to figure out when we are doing nothing at all, and I have no live orders on any exchanges.

I have zero idea where to even start on this..any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: As a rule are the start times all in order? What are other rules that apply to the sorting. With that context I'll be able to help.

Comment: @AER The start times will be sorted in order, but end times may not be (some are short duration and some are long duration).  Note that start time/end time combinations may not be unique (multiple actions happening different places same time).. Will also add some more info to question.. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """Order   Start Time               End Time
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.000  2016-08-18 09:30:05.000
1       2016-08-18 09:30:00.005  2016-08-18 09:30:25.001
1       2016-08-18 09:30:30.001  2016-08-18 09:30:56.002
1       2016-08-18 09:30:40.003  2016-08-18 09:31:05.003
1       2016-08-18 11:30:45.000  2016-08-18 13:31:05.000
2       2016-08-18 09:30:00.000  2016-08-18 09:30:05.000
2       2016-08-18 09:30:00.005  2016-08-18 09:30:25.001
2       2016-08-18 09:30:30.001  2016-08-18 09:30:56.002
2       2016-08-18 09:30:40.003  2016-08-18 09:31:05.003
2       2016-08-18 11:30:45.000  2016-08-18 13:31:05.000"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[1, 2])
```

#### Solution

```
def find_gaps(df, start_text='Start Time', end_text='End Time'):
    # rearrange stuff to get all times and a tracker
    # in single columns.
    cols = [start_text, end_text]
    df = df.reset_index()
    df1 = df[cols].stack().reset_index(-1)
    df1.columns = ['edge', 'time']
    df1['edge'] = df1['edge'].eq(start_text).mul(2).sub(1)

    # sort by ascending time, then descending edge
    # (starts before ends if equal time)
    # this will ensure we avoid zero length gaps.
    df1 = df1.sort_values(['time', 'edge'], ascending=[True, False])

    # we identify gaps when we've reached a number
    # of ends equal to number of starts.
    # we'll track that with cumsum, when cumsum is
    # zero, we've found a gap
    # last position should always be zero and is not a gap.
    # So I remove it.
    track = df1['edge'].cumsum().iloc[:-1]

    gap_starts = track.index[track == 0]
    gaps = df.ix[gap_starts]
    gaps[start_text] = gaps[end_text]
    gaps[end_text] = df.shift(-1).ix[gap_starts, start_text]

    return gaps

df.set_index('Order').groupby(level=0).apply(find_gaps)
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how this works. but is seems to work.   One thing.  When the start time on one line is equal to the end time on the prior line, it still shows in the gaps table.. any idea why that is?  Thanks

Comment: @Jeff I do know why that is. It's because the count still gets to zero. I can close those non gaps with an additional filter where I exclude gaps of length zero or something similar. I can't do it right now but I'll get to it later.

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much!  Need to digest and figure out how it works, but thanks!

Comment: I noticed that this doesn't work right when you have start times and end times that are the same - for example.. One order ends at 2016-08-18 09:30:25.001 and the next start time is 09:30:25.001.  Is there a way to account for this situation?   Thanks

Comment: @Jeff is it inconsistent?  I put something in to address that already. That's what sorting on edge is all about. If you are seeing this, it may be due to precision. Meaning the times look the same but aren't. I can help if you can share a sample of data where this happens.

Comment: Been debugging all day to see if what you are suggesting is true... might be.. Will come back - head spinning from all the data.  Thank you!